# input box asking for two specific words

Tags: javascript, input, box, inputbox

I'm new to this, so I hope I can explain well enough what my problem is.

I've got a quiz and for an answer I created an input box. To get to another link you have to put two words in there but the order should not matter aka. it shouldn't matter if you write down "word1 word2" or "word2 word1", there should be only one rule: both words should be mentioned. 
Is that possible?

My code so far:

```
        function checkText()
    {
        var textwunf_1 = document.getElementById("wunf").value;
        if(textwunf_1.toLowerCase() == "word1" && "word2"){

    window.open("URL","_self"); 

        }
    else{

    xxx 

        }
    }
```

It does not work.

Before I only wanted to check if one word is used, like that:

```
var textwunf_2 = 'word1';

    function checkText()
    {
        var textwunf_1 = document.getElementById("wunf").value;
        if(textwunf_1.toLowerCase().indexOf(textwunf_2) == -1){

    xxx

        }
    else{
            window.open("URL","_self"); 

        }
    }
```

This worked but I can't use it for two words, because if I write

```
var textwunf_2 = 'word1 word2';
```

the order can't be 'word2 word1'...

Is there a solution to my problem?

Hopefully anyone can understand and help me, thank you!

Comment: what if the user types 3 words, and two of them match with the answer ?

Comment: `indexOf` will not work as you are trying to find exact match of the words, use regex for this.

Comment: if the user types 3 words and two of them match with the answer, it should be also okay! even better if even 3 words or more are possible, as long as the user puts my two words in it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this commentary from the `OP`:

> if the user types 3 words and two of them match with the answer, it should be also okay! even better if even 3 words or more are possible, as long as the user puts my two words in it..

You can check if both words are whitin the text using two conditions on the `if`:

> textwunf_1.toLowerCase().indexOf("word1") >= 0
>
> AND
>
> textwunf_1.toLowerCase().indexOf("word2") >= 0

Try with the next code:

```
var textwunf_2 = 'word1';
var textwunf_3 = 'word2';

function checkText()
{
    var textwunf_1 = document.getElementById("wunf").value;

    if ((textwunf_1.toLowerCase().indexOf(textwunf_2) >= 0) &&
        (textwunf_1.toLowerCase().indexOf(textwunf_3) >= 0))
    {
        window.open("URL","_self");
    }
    else
    {
        // xxx
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that the user input has exactly the two mandatory words (not more, not less).

Comment: The question isn't too clear in that way, there is not a explicit sentence that say that other words can't be on the input also. Since he was using `indexOf()`, I did not assume he will need exact match. Maybe he wants to offer some flexibility to what the user inputs on the field.

Comment: Ok, he probably didn't look for exact matches. My bad.

Comment: One more thing: be aware that if the two words you were looking for were "word" and "or" a user input of "word" would suffice to pass this validation :-) .

Comment: Good point! If that is his case, I will recommend to use a regular expression instead, something like this: `textwunf_1.match(/(.*word1.*word2.*|.*word2.*word1.*)/g)`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
var words = ["word1", "word2"];

function CheckWords() {
  var inputWords = document.getElementById("wunf").value.split(' ');
  var allWordsFound = true;
  if (inputWords.length !== words.length) { return false; }
  inputWords.forEach(function(word) {
    if (words.indexOf(word.toLowerCase()) === -1) {
       allWordsFound = false;
       return;
    }
  });
  return allWordsFound;
}

console.log(CheckWords());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a function that receive the text and check if include the answers(`xx` and `yy`), it doesn't matter the order. The `ans` list, can have 1,2 or more words, it will work.

```js
let ans = ['xx','yy'];

function check(text){
  text = text.toLowerCase();
  let counter = 0;
  ans.forEach((x) => {text.includes(x) && counter++ })
  return counter === ans.length
}

console.log(check("aa bb")) // false
console.log(check("xx bb")) // false
console.log(check("aa yy")) // false
console.log(check("xx yy")) // true
console.log(check("yy xx")) // true
```